# What can I use to measure the bandwidth a specific Windows application uses?

Tags: windows, bandwidth

Ideally, I'd like to hear of an **application to show how much bandwidth each application is consuming** on my local Windows PC. Alternatively, instructions to use any other application for this purpose. The simpler the better. Something that works for Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 (if possible).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Process Explorer can help too: https://superuser.com/questions/1397822/how-can-i-see-current-network-speed-in-process-explorer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/). The free Monitor version does everything you want.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just use the built-in **Performance Monitor** to check total network bytes used by a particular process.

Just type Win+R to bring up the Run menu, and type in **perfmon**. Look in the Network section.

Comment: Yes but that's only for Vista and above.

Comment: where do I find network section?