# Program to see, which programs use the internet-connection?

Tags: internet, speed, connection

Few days ago I opened my computer as I always do after school, and got pretty amazed about my low 1.27kb/s download-speed. It has continued for few days already. We have a wireless network, which is used by 3 computers. Normally I've gotten 200kb/s (I think we have a 2mb-connection) but now it just suddenly slowed down. My friends have the same service-provider, but no problem.

So, is there any kind of program, which would show me all the programs using connection and how much? It must be a program open which just takes all speed off.

Comment: Do you have the same problem on all the computers on your network or just yours?

Comment: Everyone of them.

Comment: But it's wireless network, so if one program uses a lot of speed, others suffer from lack of speed, right?

Comment: For Linux: "Is there a way to find out what application using most of bandwidth in Linux?" at http://superuser.com/questions/32932/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-application-using-most-of-bandwidth; for Windows "What can I use to measure the bandwidth a specific Windows application uses?" at http://superuser.com/questions/66283/what-can-i-use-to-measure-the-bandwidth-a-specific-windows, and for a Mac "Is there an app for the Mac that shows you which apps are using the network?" at http://superuser.com/questions/47842/is-there-an-app-for-the-mac-that-shows-you-which-apps-are-using-the-network

Comment: Oh thanks Arjan, that will make it. If you add these links as an answer, I'll choose it :-) Thanks for everybody for help!

Comment: (@Martti, in fact I voted to close this question as a duplicate. The community will take care of that, if they agree -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your wireless is faster than you internet connection, but any computer that is sharing the connection does affect the others.

You need to verify your connection is working at the speed you expect before trying to diagnose network bottlenecks. Check what your up / down speeds should be with your provider (it is possibly on a bill) and you can begin.

You should turn off all but one computer, then make sure the remaining computer is not actively doing anything that involves the internet. Then use any of the multiple online connection speed testing web sites (google and try several for consistency) check your connection speeds.

If your tests show you have a good connection, you can try turning computers back on 1 by 1 and give them a little while to start up programs then retest your connection speed and see if you can blame a specific computer. It is possible that one on more of the computers has picked up some spyware / malware that is causing congestion on your connection.

Comment: I would suggest that you start the tests by using a wired instead of the wireless connection