# How can I see current network speed in process explorer?

Tags: windows, process-explorer

Using process explorer, how can I see how many bytes or bits send/received by a process in an instant of time say, seconds?

I couldn't find an answer to this.

Comment: Use Perfmon, which is part of Windows....https://askleo.com/how_do_i_monitor_network_activity_on_my_windows_machine/

Answer (score 1):

Open properties of the process, go to `Disk and Network` tab. Also you could see this in a main list by showing `Network Delta *` columns.
[image: Properties]
[image: Columns]

Comment: Thanks. What's delta stands for?

Comment: "Delta" means "finite increment".

Comment: Okay, then it's not really "per second" thing i.e. KB/s.

Comment: This finite increment is measured within a timeframe equal to a refresh time, used by Process Explorer. It could be 0.5-10 seconds.