# How to log application internet usage?

Tags: windows-10, internet, task-manager

We can monitor a specific application or process on task manager. However I didn’t find a way that I can record that usage over time, for example, over a month period.

Comment: There is an older question with answers you may want to check out: https://superuser.com/questions/66283/what-can-i-use-to-measure-the-bandwidth-a-specific-windows-application-uses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found out a way to check out internet usage from last 30 days. From Windows settings app > network and internet > data usage. It allows you to look up application’s specific usage.